# ES6 Promise and Class conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am very confused as to why sometimes when I use a combination of an instance of a class with a promise I get two kinds of errors.  If I use *Promise.all()* with a two or three chained promises I only sometimes get a an error of an undefined variable within the callback.  When I have a complicated class with multiple properties and methods, I have an undefined instance of my class with my *.then()*  If my class is simple and I only use one or two chained promises I have no errors.  Does anybody have any idea why this could be?  Here is an example of the code structure I am aiming for:

(The code properly executes in the latest Firefox Nightly, but not in Chrome 47)

```js
'use strict';

class Controller {
 constructor() {
  this.data = 'data';
  this.moredata = 'data';
  this.evenmore = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  this.dataobj = {"a" : "1", "b" : "2", "c" : "3"};
 }
}

//BLOCKED CODE
{
 let cc = new Controller();
 let loadeddata = null;
 
 let xhr = $.getJSON('chapters.json', {}, (response) => {
  loadeddata = response; //SOMETIMES IF CLASS IS COMPLEX IS NOT DEFINED (SOMETIMES IT IS)
 }).fail(() => {
  console.log('Failed to load JSON data!');
 });
 
 let xhr2 = $.getJSON('chapters.json', {}, (response) => {
  loadeddata = response;
 }).fail(() => {
  console.log('Failed to load JSON data!');
 });
 
 let xhr3 = $.getJSON('chapters.json', {}, (response) => {
  loadeddata = response;
 }).fail(() => {
  console.log('Failed to load JSON data!');
 });
 
 let xhr4 = $.getJSON('chapters.json', {}, (response) => {
  loadeddata = response;
 }).fail(() => {
  console.log('Failed to load JSON data!');
 });
 
 
 //SOMETIMES WITH COMPLICATED CLASS WITH ONE OR TWO PROMISES DOES NOT THROW ERROR
 Promise.all([xhr, xhr2, xhr3, xhr4]).then(() => {
  console.log(loadeddata); 
  console.log(cc); //SOMETIMES CC IS NOT DEFINED (SOMETIMES IT IS)
 });
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing native promises with jQuery defers?

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates the error, rather than `an example of the code structure I am aiming for` - it's hard to see what you are doing wrong in your code if you don't post code that is doing something wrong

Comment: I've updated the code which shows an error.  The strange thing is that I slowly added properties to the class and then added another promise, and I ended up with the same error as before, but if i delete just one thing such as the promise, I still get an error whereas before I did not.

Comment: What would the problem be if I mixed native promises with jQuery defers if they return a status?  What would be a better way?

Comment: `cc` will never be undefined in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery `$.ajax` does not return standard promise so you shouldn't use `Promise.all` with them (although you can), you can use `$.when` instead which is jquery equivalent. And instead of listening failure or success on each defered/promise you can listen on all once with `$.when`

```
var xhr1 = $.getJSON('chapters.json');
var xhr2 = $.getJSON('chapters.json');
var xhr3 = $.getJSON('chapters.json');

$.when(xhr1, xhr2, xhr1)
 .done(function(response1, response2, response3){

 })
 .fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ // first failed xhr 

 });
```

> (The code properly executes in the latest Firefox Nightly, but not in Chrome 47)

the reason it is not working in chrome 47 and working Firefox Nightly is that ES6 `class`es is not fully supported in chrome yet (it is under feature flag currently `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony` in chrome 47)

Comment: jQuery promises are standard enough (*thenable*) that `Promise.all` does work on them.

Comment: @Bergi I think I used strong words there corrected the answer